# Allocating array of 2 billion ints with msvc amd64 and QtCreator 3.0.1 (Qt 5.2.1)

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I have have a fresh install of microsoft visual studio expess C++ 2012 and Qt Creator 5.2.1 for msvc2012_64bit.

To test if my program is compiled as 64bit I print the size of a pointer and it yields 8 bytes.
So I assume it compiles in 64bit.

But when I try to allocate a block of 2 billion ints, I get a bad alloc exception. 
Is there an option I need to add to allow allocation of blocks bigger than 4GB ?

Note: I running my program on Windows 7 Home premium edition. Could there be an allocation limit ? 
I've seen there is a ram limit to 8GB.

**Edit:** 
Allocating in sequence blocks of 500 000 000 bytes stops after 14 allocations with bad allocation. This is up to 7GiB allocation in total. My physical memory is 8GB. No limitation finally. This proves that there is indeed a fragmentation problem. Increasing the ram in my PC should allow me to push the limit further. 
BTW, the maximum usable memory size for Windows 7 Home Premium is only 16GB. It's 192GB for professional or enterprise editions.

Comment: Please paste the code you used to try this allocation.

Comment: There could be many reasons for a failed allocation.  For example, the allocator must be able to allocate a *contiguous* ~8GB block for you, i.e., it needs ~8GB of *contiguous* address space.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the duplicate @EdS. I didn't know how to be sure it wasn't a compilation flag missing or whatever like that.

Comment: Per your edit, remember that your true limiting factor is virtual address space.  This takes into account physical memory *as well as* the page file (plus everything else running on your PC which requires memory.)